# Mostra Imagem na View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imagem

Estou tentando adaptar um exemplo que tenho pego aqui, para estar gravando a imagem na pasta, e mostrar tanto no INDEX quanto no EDIT, mais esta ocorrendo algumas divergências. Conforme segue abaixo meu código fonte, caso possam estar orientando-me no sentido de que eu possa ajustar o programa para que o mesmo possa funcionar, agradeço a todos que postarem no auxilio, grato.

DOMÍNIO

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApp.Dominio
{
    public class FrmCadFuncionario : IDisposable
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [DisplayName("Código")]
        public int T_FrmCadFuncionarioId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o Nome")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
        [DisplayName("Nome")]
        public string T_FrmCadFuncionarioNome { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Foto")]
        public string T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
namespace MvcApp.Controllers
{
    public class FrmCadFuncionarioController : Controller
    {
        private IConnection Connection;
        private FrmCadFuncionarioAplicacao CadFuncionarioAplicacao;
        public FrmCadFuncionarioController()
        {
            Connection = new Connection();
            CadFuncionarioAplicacao = new FrmCadFuncionarioAplicacao(Connection);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (CadFuncionarioAplicacao != null) CadFuncionarioAplicacao.Dispose();
            if (Connection != null) Connection.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

------ INDEX da paginas -----
        public ActionResult Index(int? page, string filtro)
        {
            ViewBag.filtro = filtro ?? string.Empty;
            return View(CadFuncionarioAplicacao.Pagination(page ?? 1, 10, filtro));
        }

----- CREATE -----  Esta gravando na pasta a imagem com o ID e a extensão do arquivo
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FrmCadFuncionario cadfuncionario, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            CadFuncionarioAplicacao.Create(cadfuncionario);
            if (file != null)
            {
                String[] strName = file.FileName.Split('.');
                String strExt = strName[strName.Count() - 1];
                string pathSave = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/"), cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId, strExt);
                String pathBase = String.Format("/Imagens/Fotos_Func/{0}.{1}", cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId, strExt);
                file.SaveAs(pathSave);
                cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioPathFoto = pathBase;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


-----EDIT - Não esta conseguindo encontrar a pasta das imagens
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(CadFuncionarioAplicacao.Find(id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FrmCadFuncionario cadfuncionario, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CadFuncionarioAplicacao.Edit(cadfuncionario);
                if (file != null)
                {
                    if (cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto != null)
                    {
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/" + cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/" + cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto));
                        }
                    }
                    String[] strName = file.FileName.Split('.');
                    String strExt = strName[strName.Count() - 1];
                    string pathSave = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/"), cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId, strExt);
                    String pathBase = String.Format("/Imagens/Fotos_Func/{0}.{1}", cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId, strExt);
                    file.SaveAs(pathSave);
                    cadfuncionario.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto = pathBase;
                    CadFuncionarioAplicacao.Edit(cadfuncionario);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(cadfuncionario);
        }


---- INDEX - Não esta encontrando a pasta das imagens gravadas
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {

            try
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/" + filename));
                    string filepathtosave = "Imagens/Fotos_Func/" + filename;
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Ocorreu com sucesso.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            return View();

        }



 VIEW INDEX - Não esta mostrando as imagens na tela
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h3 class="heading">Consulta Funcionários</h3>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table_vam" id="dt_gal">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="table_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="select_rows" class="select_rows" data-tableid="dt_gal" /></th>

                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th data-bsortable="true">Nome</th>
                                <th>Endereço</th>
                                <th>Numero</th>
                                <th>Bairro</th>
                                <th>Cidade</th>
                                <th>Imagem</th>
                                <th>Acoes</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var Items in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="row_sel" class="row_sel" /></td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioNome)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioEndereco)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioNumero)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioBairro_Nome)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioCidade_Nome)</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>
                                            @Html.LabelFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)<br />
                                            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(c => Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)" alt="Uploaded Image" />
                                            <br />
                                        </p>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId})" class="sepV_a" title="Editar"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId })" title="Deletar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>



VIEW EDIT - Não esta mostrando a imagem na tela
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "FrmCadFuncionario", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Edit Registro </legend>
                           <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="formSep">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <div class="vcard">
                                                <div data-fileupload="image" class="fileupload fileupload-new">
                                                    <div style="width: 220px; height: 220px;" class="fileupload-new thumbnail">
                                                        <img src="~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/FundoImage.png" alt="" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div style="width: 220px; height: 220px; line-height: 220px;"
                                                         class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br />

                                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                            <span>       </span>
                                                            <div class="span2">
                                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId)
                                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId, new { style = "width:120px;", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId)
                                                            </div>

                                                    if (model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto != null)
                                                        {
                                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                            <div class="span4">
                                                                <img src="~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/" alt="" />
                                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)
                                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto, new { style = "width: 250px" })
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                            <div class="span4">
                                                                <img src="~/img/FundoImage.png" alt="" />
                                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)
                                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto, new { @class = "file-loading", @type = "file", @name = "file" })
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                       }

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Tenho feito o projeto, visando a inclusão da imagem(foto) do funcionário na ficha de cadastro, e quando na abertura dos registros apresentados no INDEX, mostrar também a imagem. Só que na operação do INDEX e no EDIT, não esta mostrando a foto, esse o problema que esta ocorrendo no meu código, caso alguém tenha passado por este problema e queira orientar-me, agradeço a todos que postarem no auxilio, grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia user34823,
Você pode estar utilizando o URL.CONTENT para isto:

Exemplo:

```html
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/" + Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)" alt="@Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioNome" />
```

Qualquer dúvida só perguntar!

Comment: Ola Oziel, eu fiz conforme havia descrito. Não esta aparecendo a imagem ainda, fico grato pela dica.obrg.                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Imagens/Fotos_Func/" + Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto)" alt="@Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioId" />, inseri dentro do INDEX para verificar. Obs.: Será que não esta faltando algo no controller por isso a não amostragem da imagem?.

Comment: Tenho feito o projeto, visando a inclusão da imagem(foto) do funcionário na ficha de cadastro, e quando na abertura dos registros apresentados no INDEX, mostrar também a imagem. Só que na operação do INDEX e no EDIT, não esta mostrando a foto, esse o problema que esta ocorrendo no meu código, caso alguém tenha passado por este problema e queira orientar-me, agradeço a todos que postarem no auxilio, grato.

Comment: Olá boa tarde @user34823, eu utilizo este mesmo código aqui para a exibição de imagens. Verifique se está chegando algum valor nos seus atributos **`Items.T_FrmCadFuncionarioFoto`**. A única diferença do que eu tenho aqui para o que te informei é que eu troquei o meu atributo de URL para este em que você apresentou na pergunta.